# No module named freetext - Django

Tags: django, freetext

I have a problem with django module named [freetext](https://github.com/howiworkdaily/django-freetext).

There is no info how to install it in Django. I'm getting this error while trying to run Django on new server:

```
[Mon May 28 13:47:45 2012] [error] mod_wsgi (pid=27668): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/sites/somod/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Mon May 28 13:47:45 2012] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon May 28 13:47:45 2012] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[Mon May 28 13:47:45 2012] [error]     self.load_middleware()
[Mon May 28 13:47:45 2012] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
[Mon May 28 13:47:45 2012] [error]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Mon May 28 13:47:45 2012] [error] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware shop.cart.middleware: "No module named freetext"
```

How can I install this module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way:

```
pip install -e https://github.com/howiworkdaily/django-freetext.git
```

Update, that doesn´t work because that app doesn´t have a setup.py, so clone it and put it in somewhere PYTHONPATH can find it, or better like a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Or just inside your django project:

```
git clone https://github.com/howiworkdaily/django-freetext.git freetext
```

at the same level of your manage.py

Comment: Thanks for update. I have tried to use second command, but im getting this error: `Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/vhosts/somodfurniture.co.uk/sites/somod/freetext/.git/
fatal: https://github.com/howiworkdaily/djnago-freetext.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?` Firts also didnt work

Comment: Dont give me -, but i dont know. Im using CentOS 6, python 2.6, wsgi, but i dont know anything about git. Is there a way i could check it?

Comment: The better now is just download the code (click in the zip button in github) and uncompress it in the same folder where you manage.py resides

Comment: Thanks, that works I think, because I'm getting different errors.